# How to login faster using a domain account when the domain is unavailable

Tags: active-directory, windows-authentication, local-system

I have a laptop with Windows 7 ultimate enterprise edition installed. This is a company laptop  so i have domain account as I am a domain user but also a local administrator on my laptop.
My problem is that now i am out of the company premises for some days and when i login via my account it takes a hell lot of time to login because it tries to authenticate me on the domain (probably).
Can i someway disable this "searching for the domain network" so that i login faster, like a local login account on the laptop does?

Answer (score 1):

Your IT department probably doesn't want you logging-on with a local account. As a second-best strategy, I'd recommend you try disabling your wireless NIC and not connecting any wired network cables until after you've logged-on. The total absence of network connectivity should cause the logon process to proceed speedily with cached credentials.

Comment: Well actually they have given me this laptop for use in case i am traveling. I have already tried disabling the wireless and then logging but it does not work out.

Answer (score 0):

Login to windows when your not connected to any network. That way windows wont be trying to search for an AD server.

Once your logged in, plug-in your cable/turn on your wifi.

Comment: I have tried to do the same, i disabled my wireless connection and logged in but there was no difference.
The only solution out was to create another local account with local administrator privileges. Which has its own issues that it is not same as the built in Administrator account as i keep on running into other access related issues.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem as well not so long ago. Our fix was to change the DNS settings to match the domain controller (i.e. our AD server).
If this works for you, you could have your AD server as your primary DNS and some other public DNS such as OpenDNS as the secondary so that you can still access the internet.

Comment: It is a requirement that domain members use the AD DNS if they are to function correctly. You shouldn't be using a secondary DNS server that isn't part of AD either, or it will give you all sorts of weird problems when connected to the corporate network.

Most corporate networks (and home/public networks) will use DHCP, so you shouldn't need to touch DNS at all, as it will just do the right thing when you move between networks.

Comment: Oh yes, didn't think about that - so if a primary DNS can't be found (if one is explicitly defined in the adapter properties), it will fall back to the router and do what ever is defined there; correct?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound normal, but I've seen the same behaviour before (albeit on Windows XP).

In our case, it was a logon script that attempting to pipe the output of some commands to a network share. As the logon script was cached, but the network share wasn't available the logon process took far longer than it should have done when not connected to the corporate network.

Try [enabling verbose user environment logging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221833) and then logging on with the network disconnected, once it does let you in, review the userenv.log file and see what is causing the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any mapped drives or saved locations that point to a network drive? That has caused issues w/ some of my users. Check to see if you have any log on scripts running that would be doing the mapping.